# Is it OK to have a method return different types based on a parameter?

Tags: coding-style

I'm looking for a reference to clean coding styles that I can pass to a team member.

In particular, the rule that a method should not change its return type based on an input parameter. If you need different output, use a different method.

Example:

```
$invoice_items = getInvoiceItems();
$total         = getInvoiceItems( TRUE );
```

To me, this is bad coding style (and I'm not even talking about a parameter whose meaning can't be determined from the calling code).

The above example should actually be:

```
$total = totalInvoiceItems();
```

... where `totalInvoiceItems()` might call `getInvoiceItems()` to get the items it needs to total.

Where would I find a reference to this (and possibly other important coding style rules)?

Comment: If your language supports structs or tuples, it can be used by the function to return any combinations of partial results. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861353/structs-data-type-in-php

Answer (score 14):

As Eric said, the boolean flag as a behavior selector is a tell-tale sign that something's wrong with the function's contract.

#### Reasons, why this is a problem

- The function contract is unnecessarily complicated. It's easy to explain the contract of a function that simply returns all invoice items, just as well as it is easy to explain a function that takes a list of invoice items and returns the sum of their payment amounts. It's much more involved to explain the optional boolean parameter version.
- The function name is not telling you what the function does anymore. `getInvoiceItems` sounds like it should give me some items, not a sum value. Analogously, splitting it into two functions gives you something like `sumOfInvoiceItems($items)`, which is self-explanatory again.
- The function implementation itself is unnecessarily complicated. The simpler a function, the easier it is to understand, explain, verify, ... More complex functions are better at attracting bugs, so simple is better.

#### References

- The main reference about clean code is of course the [book of the same name](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882) by Uncle Bob. You will find more detailled reasoning there for keeping your functions short and simple with clean contracts and to name them well.
- Albeit it is usually applied to classes, instead of functions, the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) can also be applied to a function. But anyways, the SRP also stems from Uncle Bob, so I guess the real reference is just Uncle Bob himself.

Answer (score 5):

Functions should behave consistently.
There is a second function hidden in functions with a boolean parameter anyway.

If there is a branch inside the function with two mostly different behaviors, why not make it two function and maybe factor the common code into a third? Is there a shortage of function declarators?